# How to change the default organization selected for a user?

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm-2013, dynamics-crm-2015

In the earlier versions of CRM, the default organization could be set from Deployment Manager. It's not the case anymore, though. Now, every user gets his own default depending on the **first organization ever accessed** on the server.

I have strong (and less than favorable) opinions on the subject but it seems that Microsoft cares very little what I think.

So, I'm going to do the following to the DB.

```
use MSCRM_CONFIG

update SystemUser 
set DefaultOrganizationId = 'GUID of the main organization'
--where Id='GUID of a user'
```

However, I'm concerned that it'll break something and cause an eternity to restore, so I'm verifying by asking the question here.

1. How can I ensure beyond any possible doubts that I've got the correct GUID for the organization?
2. Will it work well when commenting the clause targeting the individual users and hitting all of them in one swing?
3. What other consideration should I have, except backing up the whole system prior to the operation?

And if anybody can suggest a smoother and less intrusive way, I'll be jumping of joy.

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize the script at http://complexitykills.blogspot.com/2009/09/default-organization-for-user-is.html which is similar to yours, but has a little bit more logging included with it - note in the comments that there's a comment to include a where clause condition looking for Organization that has "IsDeleted = 0" to prevent selecting an organization that has been deleted.  If issue your SQL Command inside of a SQL Transaction, you can run the script, validate users can still login to Microsoft CRM, and if needed, quickly issue a "Rollback Tran" to roll the SQL transaction back rather than having to perform a complete restore of the MSCRM_CONFIG database (although that should be quick to restore as that's never very large as far as SQL Server databases are concerned).

To get the correct OrganizationID, you can use a SQL Query like this:

```
DECLARE @DefaultOrganizationId AS VARCHAR (100);
SET @DefaultOrganization = '<organizationname>';

SELECT @DefaultOrganizationId = id
FROM   MSCRM_CONFIG..organization
WHERE  UniqueName = @DefaultOrganization AND IsDeleted = 0;
```

If you don't have the where clause included, it will indeed update all of the users to the organizationid you have added here and should work well (see the query above for an example of how to retrieve the organizationid from the MSCRM_CONFIG..organization table).

This is not necessarily a common operation, but I have seen it used with a few organizations to successfully update the default organization associated to a user, noting that precautions were made before hand to back up the databases and testing was performed after to ensure everything worked for these users in Microsoft CRM.